# Send data from view pager to activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an application that contains a 3-steps register activity. Those 3 steps are divided into 3 fragments with veiwpager to swipe back and forward and in the last step there is a register button that when pressed the data will be sent to a database which will be done in the `Register` Activity.

I'm facing a problem in passing all the data the user enters in the 3 fragments to the `Register` Activity.

I was thinking on saving the data of each fragment when swiping to the next fragment but i got confused!

Register Activity:

```
public class Register extends FragmentActivity {
  ViewPager pager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){
      // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      }

      // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

      }

      // Called when the scroll state changes:
      // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // Code goes here
      }
    });
  }

  private static String makeFragmentName(int viewPagerId, int index) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + index;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_register, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Register XML:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

First Fragment:

```
public class personal_info_fragment extends Fragment {

  private EditText fname,lname,pass,conf_pass,phone_nb,license_nb;
  private Spinner age_spinner;
  private RadioButton male_rb,female_rb;
  private String first_name,last_name,license,phone,password,conf_password;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_info_fragment, container, false);

    fname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.fname);
    lname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.lname);
    license_nb = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.license_nb);
    pass = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pass);
    conf_pass = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.conf_pass);
    phone_nb = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_nb);

    return v;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public static personal_info_fragment newInstance(String text) {

    personal_info_fragment f = new personal_info_fragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
  }
}
```

First Fragment XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/personal_info"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fname"
        android:hint="@string/fname"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lname"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/lname"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/license_nb"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/license_nb"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/pass"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/conf_pass"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/conf_pass"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_nb"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/phone"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:id="@+id/male_rb" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:id="@+id/female_rb" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/age_spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the second and the third fragments is similar to first fragment.

Page Adapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch(pos) {
      case 0:
        return new personal_info_fragment();
      case 1:
        return new medical_info_fragment();
      case 2:
        return new car_info_fragment();
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch(position) {
      case 0:
        return "Personal Information";
      case 1:
        return "Medical Information";
      case 2:
        return "Car Information";
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

THANKS in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an interface. Something like this:

```java
public interface ConnectActivityAndFragments {
    void sendData(Bundle data);
}
```

Your activity should implement this interface and override this method:

```java
@Override
public void sendData(Bundle data) {
    Fragment oneFr = new Fragment();
    oneFr.setArguments(data);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, oneFr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Now in your fragment you need to get instance of your interface, attach fragment to your activity and you'll be able to use that method.Something like this:

```java
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        yourActivityControl =  (ConnectActivityAndFragments) getActivity();

    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            throw ex;
    }
}
void getData(){
    yourActivityControl.sendData(Your Bundle with Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this idea:

A `ViewPager` concept in a registration process is perhaps not the best solution here. View Pagers are used to make navigation easier and fast but now the challenge comes when you have to pass a good amount of data / input.

The likely approach would be to create 3 `Activitities`. For example:

```
PersonalInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{}

MedicalInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{}

CarInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity{}
```

Instead of having 3 `Fragments` plus `MainActivity` which makes your total classes 4, you will end up with just 3 classes using this approach and then you can simply pass the extras from first activity to the second and in the third activity you can simply do your registration or whatever you wanted to do.

So, in summary,

- In the first activity, have a NEXT button which when clicked gets the input entered in the first activity and transitions into the second activity (perhaps use a smooth transition here to avoid a big change in the eyes of the users like a Slide In maybe).
- In the second activity, extract using the intent, the information from activity one and store in local variables as the user inputs data there. Once done, using a button like in activity 1, when clicked, pass both values from activity one and the second activity to the last activity.
- Finally, extract the values from activity 1 and 2 in activity 3 and once the user has finished entering data into the forms in activity 3, you can easily send them or store them!

I hope this breakdown helps you get an idea.

Comment: I already thought of your solution which is obviously the the easy way to implement such activity like you said, but I'm new to the fragment thing and i want to learn how to deal with them.Anyway my problem is solved and thank you for your advice.